# Can you please tell me why I am getting `The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled.` error message

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have been able to work through the initial problem of not being able to insert records consistently but a new error message crops up.

Now, I am getting `The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled.`

This error occurs when I click the Update button to update a row of record.

First, I click Edit button. This exposes the Update/Cancel buttons.

When I click the Update button, I get the aforementioned error.

My first take was that gridview needed onRowUpdating but after adding (see markup code), still getting same error.

This is a bit frustrating.

Here is the code.

```vb
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim dd As DropDownList = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlstatus"), DropDownList)
    e.NewValues("status") = dd.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub
```

Markup:

```asp
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="reqnum" AllowPaging="True" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Visible="True" 
        OnRowDataBound="gvRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
        EnableViewState="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rownum" HeaderText="rownum" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="rownum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="reqnum" HeaderText="reqnum" SortExpression="reqnum"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="reqrecdate" HeaderText="reqrecdate" SortExpression="reqrecdate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="reqrecfrom" HeaderText="reqrecfrom" SortExpression="reqrecfrom" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="skillsets" HeaderText="skillsets" SortExpression="skillsets" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="application" HeaderText="application" SortExpression="application" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="hoursperweek" HeaderText="hoursperweek" SortExpression="hoursperweek" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fromdate" HeaderText="fromdate" SortExpression="fromdate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="todate" HeaderText="todate" SortExpression="todate" />
       <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="status" SortExpression="status" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="status">
          <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList id="ddlstatus" CssClass="dropdown" DataSourceID="DSforDDL" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem Text="none" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>Not Started</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>Pending</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>Completed</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("status") %>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="statusupdate" HeaderText="statusupdate" SortExpression="statusupdate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="statusupby" HeaderText="statusupby" SortExpression="statusupby" />
      </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT Distinct [rownum],[reqnum], [reqrecdate], [reqrecfrom], [skillsets], [application], [hoursperweek], [fromdate], [todate], [status], [statusupdate], [statusupby] FROM [Term] ORDER BY [reqnum]" 
UpdateCommand="INSERT INTO Term(reum, reqrecdate, reqrecfrom, skillsets, application, hoursperweek, fromdate, todate, status, statusupby, statusupdate) VALUES (@reum,@reqrecdatelbltxt, @reqrecfromlbltxt, @skillsets, @application, @hoursperweek,@fromdate,@todate, @status, @lognametxt, @logdatetxt)"

    <DeleteParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="rownum" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="reqnum" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="reqrecdate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="reqrecfrom" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="skillsets" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="application" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="hoursperweek" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="fromdate" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="todate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="statusupdate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="statusupby" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="rownum" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your assistance.

Comment: I'm curious why your gridview's update command contains an 'insert' statement ?

Comment: @Damien, problem is that it doesn't matter whether it is an update statement with UpdateCommand or Insert statement with InsertComment or Insert statement with UpdateCommand, it still doesn't save the data into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gridView tracks handlers to ensure something has been added to deal with the update intentionally.

Unless you are Manually calling "AddHandler" somewhwere else in code, I don't see a **handles** claus on your event method that would intercept the event being raised.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I suppose you mean adding this `Handles GridView1.RowUpdating` to the `GridView1_RowUpdating` sub. I added that but still getting same error.

Comment: In one of my projects using the grid this way I am handling "RowCancellingEdit", "RowCommand", "RowDeleting", "RowEditing", "RowUpdating" and all the functions are working. Possibly they have mislabeled one of the feedback messages, try adding an empty routine handling each of those.